# ReCaptcha response returning recaptcha-v3-token value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-platform, recaptcha-v3

I am using reCaptcha v3 service in our project, user can enable/disable the reCaptcha services if they want. Sometimes the form data contains (this happens only if the user disabled reCaptcha services in site)

```
{ g-recaptcha-response: "", recaptcha-v3-token: "" }
```

while submitting a form. I don't have any idea why this is happening.

I have implemented the reCaptcha v3 service in our web forms, sometimes I am receiving the unexpected response in a form data. I need some idea about this issue.